# Save the maximum of data with python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a big data frame (14173,3193) consisting of the historical price of us stocks.

```
index             A       AA        ...         ZZZ
1962-01-01        nan     nan       ...         nan
...               100     3         ...         nan
2017-08-01        nan     5         ...         12
```

As you can see a lot of nan in this df because some stocks existed in 1962 and not in 2010, some in 2017 and not in 1962....

As you can see I have a lot of NaN and I would like to remove them.

I created a newdf with the monthly price with the resample function to delete some nan (day with no stock exchange for example)

```
dftest = df.resample('M').mean()
```

I have now a df=(670,3193)

To delete some other nan I selected only the dates with the more data

```
df = df.iloc[470:,:]
```

And delete the column with a NaN

```
dftest = dftest.dropna(axis=1)
```

My final df size is (200,1528)

A lot of data lost. Is there a function to minimize the loss of my data? I mean a function to know the maximum numbers of rows and columns full of data we can have?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do with your data.

Comment: Trying to reproduce the idea behind this paper (https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2614233). Trading strategie, cointegration, some test, return, ssd,... from what i read.

Comment: Based on a 30 second scan of the paper, why delete the NAN values. Just run the analysis with stocks that exist, and update as new IPOs happen

Comment: I thought it would be easier to delete all NAN to do the test. And i dont have much data for the first stocks (maybe 150 stocks without NAN in the period <1985) so the result could be bad. I think it is better to work with at least 400 stocks. Is there a way to know from what rows i have 400 or more non NAN in a row?